# idFTP takes too long to give connection result

Tags: delphi, ftp, connection, indy

I developped an application that uses indy component to download updates from a remote server.
The problem is that if the FTP server is down or the IP address is not correct, the idFTP.connect() takes too long to give the result (connection failure).

What is the best way to accelerate the connection answer, or may be checking ip address before connection to idFTP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Riad, I've just been through all of your previous questions. Are you sure none of them got an acceptable answer? Because it sure looks like you just forgot to tick the accepted answer mark.

Comment: Sorry, I'll tick the acceptable ones

Comment: Perhaps you would need to set up your Windows TCP/IP layer timeout settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, native connect() API timeouts are notoriously lengthy by design, (to accommodate high latency links like modems).  Artificially shortening the timeout may result in premature failure notification, (though as many developers have never seen a modem, it's not that much of a problem today:).

FTP is a reasonably complex transfer requiring two TCP connections and perhaps a DNS lookup - any of these could conceivably generate long connection delays. TidFTP has an inherited 'ReadTimeout' property and a connect() overload with a timeout parameter, but I'm not sure how effective they are.

Historically, I have always timed out such operations myself using a TTimer or similar - if the FTP thread does not respond with a suitable signal, (eg. TThread.Sychronize or user-defined Windows message SendMessage()'d to the GUI), in time, a 'FTP failed' actions are taken and a flag is set in the FTP thread that tells it to ignore any replies and self-terminate.  Don't use PostMessage - if you do, there is a small window of time in which a posted response my be queued up while the TTimer is firing - a race.

Oh - and if you are just plonking a TidFTP onto the form, (or creating one in TForm.FormCreate), and trying to run it from the main GUI thread, (with, or without, TidAntiFreeze), stop doing it and thread off the FTP.

Comment: The `Timeout` parameter of `Connect()` only applies to Indy 9 and earlier.  In Indy 10, it was replaced with a new `ConnectTimeout` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should set ReadTimeout property, by default it is set to one minute.

Comment: I already tried that, the property was set to 0, I tried to change it but the result was the same

Comment: @riad The key here is that it takes time to find out that there is a problem. The computer has to send a packet (or many), and awaits a response from the other end. Only after a time can it know if it worked or not. All you can do is stop waiting earlier. From a user point of view, you might put this in a thread to allow them to do other things, but there is fundamentally nothing you can do.

Comment: @mj2008, thanks for your reply, that is exactly what I did before posting the question, I thought that I may miss other properties in idFTP. But after checking the answers and comments, I think the only way is to put the connection in a thread.

Comment: `ReadTimeout` is set to `INFINITE` by default.  There is also a separate `ConnectTimeout` property in Indy 10 (an `ATimeout` parameter on `Connect()` itself in Indy 9) that is also set to `INFINITE` by default. If the `Connect()` timeout is set to 0 and `TIdAntiFreeze` is used, then `Connect()` uses a 2 minute timeout.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Indy clients wait as long as it takes for the OS to report whether the connection was successful or not.  Yes, that can take a long time, if the OS has to look up the hostname with DNS, do network checks, deal with network latency, etc.  If you do not want to wait that long, you can use the `Timeout` parameter of `Connect()` in Indy 9 and earlier, or the `ConnectTimeout` property in Indy 10, to reduce the amount of time waited on.  **HOWEVER**, that only applies to the actual socket connect attempt once the server IP has been determined.  If you set the `Host` property to a non-IP hostname, Indy asks the OS to perform a DNS lookup to get the hostname's IP, and there is no logic available in `Connect()` to control the time it takes to do that lookup.  If you need that much control, then use `TIdDNSResolver` to get the IP manually and then assign it to the `Host` property before calling `Connect()`.